# Issue with LWP::Simple and https when upgrading to ActivePerl v5.26.3

Tags: perl, ssl, lwp

I have recently upgraded from ActivePerl v5.20.2 to v5.26.3.

There is now a SSL problem with LWP::Simple::get with some sites

e.g.

```
#!c:/Perl64/bin/Perl.exe
# test perl scripts
use LWP::Simple;
#
$url = "https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/rugby-union";
$content = get($url);
print "get succesful - ", length($content), " bytes read\n";
$url = "https://www.theguardian.com/cartoons/archive";
$content = get($url);
print "get succesful - ", length($content), " bytes read\n";
```

works fine with the old version but with the new gives

get succesful - 214904 bytes read

Free to wrong pool 977970 not 890014001a5d9a5e at C:/Perl64/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 2739.

Line 2739 of SSL.pm is

```
my $certid = eval { Net::SSLeay::OCSP_cert2ids($ssl,$cert) };
```

so it's something to do with certificate handling.

Comment: The problem doesn't have a relation with the module, I think it may be related to your OS that is windows, most of this type of errors are generated when using Windows (mostly when using threads)

Comment: That message indicates a bug in an XS module such Net::SSLeay. Specifically, it's a bug related to thread support (or lack thereof). Contrary to what the previous comment said, there's no reason to believe it's Windows-specific at this point.

Comment: See [Using Net::SSLeay in multi-threaded applications](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay#Using-Net::SSLeay-in-multi-threaded-applications).

Comment: Please provide the versions of IO::Socket::SSL, Net::SSLeay and openssl used by this build of Perl - see https://pastebin.com/Y5MD2auR for a script to help you with this.

Comment: Thanks. I ran your script which gave LWP 6.08 LWP::Protocol::https 6.06 IO::Socket::SSL 1.997. I have reported the bug to ActiveState. I am running Windows 10 with all updates installed.

Comment: @SamNodes: The script should have reported the versions for Net::SSLeay and openssl too, but you did not include these in your comment. Anyway, these looks like pretty old software versions too me. For example IO::Socket::SSL 1.997 was released nearly 5 years ago and there were lots of bug fixes and improvements since then. Maybe you should switch to Strawberry Perl which has way newer software versions.

Comment: Apologies - I didn't cut/paste enough. Net::SSLeay 1.84 openssl 1010008f - OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018. I'll certainly look into Strawberry Perl.

Comment: I've installed Strawberry perl which has newer versions of all the packages in @SteffenUllrich's list and my script works! I had to restart Apache web server before cgi-bin scripts using get() would work properly but otherwise all is good. Thanks.